# Can I visit other Schengen countries while on a French student visa?

Tags: schengen, france, long-stay-visas

I have student visa 'D'. Is it possible for me to travel and stay in other Schengen countries like Belgium, Germany, etc.?

Comment: Basically yes. You should not stay more than 90 days in any 180-day period and there are a few more other rules but you can certainly visit other countries in the Schengen area.

Comment: There's another dupe specifically about french long-term visas too.